# Notification icon with lowercase "a" with a curved line below it resembles the mouth of a smiley face

Tags: notification-icons

I am trying to identify an icon on my kids phone. I noticed it and I am unfamiliar so I am a little nervous. It was a notification icon so I don't know what the app itself is. The icon is essentially a lowercase "a" in the exact font that this message is in with a curved line below it that resembles the mouth of a smiley face. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Amazon Appstore, which notifies Android users through the notification bar that its store application has an update available. You can confirm this by either clicking the notification icon, or by starting the Appstore itself. The Appstore's early startup actions presents a dialog that a new version is available, and allowing the user to decide to install it.

Comment: Thank you. I googled it and that is it. Such a big relief. Its hard to tell anymore and with the craziness in the world I just wanted to be sure